# Assign and create new String difference

Tags: java, string

```
        String s1 = new String("string");
        String s2 = new String("string");

        String s3 = "string";
        String s4 = "string";

        System.out.println(s1 == s2);      //FALSE
        System.out.println(s2.equals(s1)); //TRUE

        System.out.println(s3 == s4);      //TRUE
        System.out.println(s3.equals(s4)); //TRUE
```

**What is the difference between creation of `s1` and `s3`** ?
Please let me know

In String we are having only String object then why it treats this two differently.
s1 and s2 are having different memory address while s3 and s4 has same memory address.
why it works based on **`new`** operator.?

Comment: If you want to make you concepts clear in java String Please read KathySierra Scjp 6 . The chapter No.6 String has wonderful explaination on string means no one can't explain better then her. If you want the pdf just give ur mailID to me at nikhilagrawal60@gmail.com. If someone else is interested then they also can mail me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `String` objects that represent string literals in your Java source code are added to a shared `String` pool when the classes that defines them are loaded<sup>1</sup>.  This ensures that all "copies" of a String literal are actually the same object ... even if the literal appears in multiple classes.  That is why `s3 == s4` is `true`.

By contrast, when you `new` a String, a distinct new String object is created.  That is why `s1 == s2` is `false`.  (This is a fundamental property of `new`.  It is guaranteed to create and return a new object ... if it completes normally.)

However, in either case, the strings will have the same characters, and that is why `equals` is returning `true`.

---

While it is important to understand what is going on, the *real* lesson is that the *correct* way to compare Java strings is to use `equals` and not `==`.

If you want to arrange that your String objects can be tested for equality using `==`, you can "intern" them using the `String.intern` method.  However, you have to do this consistently ... and interning is an expensive process in various respects ... so it is generally not a good idea.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, it is a bit more complicated than that.  They objects get added to the pool at some time between class loading and first use of the literals.  The precise timing is unspecified and JVM implementation dependent.  However it is guaranteed to happen just once, and before any application code sees the `String` object reference corresponding to the literal.</sup>

Comment: why interning is an expensive process?

Comment: A number of factors.  1)  There is a hash table that uses memory and is probed / updates when you call `intern`.  2)  Each interned string has to be stored in the hash table using a weak reference.  That's extra memory + GC overhead.  3) The interned strings are stored in the (generally limited) "permgen" space.  GC'ing permgen typically entails a full GC.

Comment: great explanation. I read somewhere, Java 1.7 Strings don't go into the PermGen area of heap? is that true?

Comment: @AmitG - AFAIK, Java 1.7 handles Strings the same way as previously.  The rule about String literals is specified in the JLS.  It is not implementation dependent.

Comment: @AmitG - In Java 1.8, there is no permgen.  But that is immaterial to the *observable* semantics of string literals ... except in the edge case where the (pre-Java 8) permgen heap is full.

Answer (score 3):

`s1` is a new String object that does not belong to a part of any **pooled instance**. `s3` is an instance of a string that comes from a pool. Lookup **java String pool**. Take a look at the related [intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method on `String`.

The concept is not unique to java. [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is supported in other languages. On that related note, pooling frequently used objects follows the [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern and is not limited to Strings. Take a look at `Integer.valueOf()`. Integers have a constant pool of their own too.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM has an automatic optimisation. Unless you specifically create a new `String` object, and another `String` object already exists with the same value, the `JVM` automatically assumes that a new object is not a necessity, and will assign you a pointer to the equal `String` object that already exists.

Essentially, when you use the second option, this is what happens:

**Step 1**

First Object is created no problem.

**Step 2**

Before the second object is created, the String pool is checked for a value.
If that value currently exists, then there is no need to create a new object. It just returns the reference to the `String` object.

**Step 3**

Instead of being assigned a new Object, it is simply given a reference to the object made in step 1. This is to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `new` operator forces creation of a new instance of String, while in the second case, as `String` is an immutable class, the JVM provides you with the same String instance for both variables to save memory. As there is no chance one of such objects will change causing the second one change as well (immutable, remember?) this is OK.